# Unity PHP to SSMS

Tags: php, sql, ssms

I have two tables: one for user credentials and another for inputting remarks.

Table 1 (User credentials):

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1007 | max |
| 1008 | james |

Table 2 (Input remarks to the user ID):

| id | remarks |
| --- | --- |
| 1007 | user input 1 |
| 1007 | user input 2 |
| 1008 | user input 1 |

Currently, this is my code

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO remarks (id) SELECT id FROM testing WHERE id = ?", array($loginID));

if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Record inserted successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error inserting record: " . sqlsrv_errors();
}

$stmt1 = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO remarks (remarks) VALUES (?)", array($remarks1));
if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt1)) {
    echo "Record inserted successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error inserting record: " . sqlsrv_errors();
}
```

What should I change my php code to?

Comment: What do you mean by "to SSMS"? SQL Server Management Studio is just an IDE like application used for products like SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure Synapse, etc.

Comment: Apologies. I'm connecting Unity to SSMS through PHP. Hence, SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server and SSMS aren't synonyms. If you're trying to connect to SSMS then you're trying to connect to an IDE like application, not a database engine. Saying you want to connect to SSMS (instead of SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge, etc) is like stating you want to make an application and write it in the language Visual Studio.